# Design a passive amplifier

Tags: voltage, amplifier, passive-networks, lumped

I am trying to increase the amplitude of my generated electrical signal by a passive amplifier. I have seen so many complex RLC circuits. But I have limited space for design, therefore, can I use a simple lumped RLC model as an amplifier? Is there any other passive component that can be used for amplification?

Comment: Please describe your "generated electrical signal"...voltage, current, frequency, etc.

Comment: A harmonic oscillator would work but only for certain frequency/-ies. I'm afraid what others have said is true, no such thing. (edit) Oscillator is a bad chosen word which would imply active amplification, I meant an undamped passive filter.

Comment: Which are you trying to amplify?...voltage or current? If your source signal has a lower impedance than your load impedance, **voltage** amplification is possible for AC signals, using a LC network.

Comment: A transformer is the only solution that comes to mind with a limited BW of 2 to 3 decades

Comment: I need to amplify the voltage of the generated electrical signal. I used LC network for generating an electrical signal but the amplitude is not sufficient for my system. Therefore, I am looking for any suggestions on how to amplify it.

Answer (score 3):

A "passive amplifier" is an oxymoron. No, you can't make an amplifier from R, L, C or other passive components.

Comment: Well, if you only need AC voltage amplification (not power amplification) there's a transformer.  Not practical for all purposes, but it is kind of a passive amplifier.

Comment: @JohnD Fair enough, if the signal is AC then a transformer might do the trick.

Comment: You can make a frequency specific voltage amplifier with an LC circuit. Just saying!

Comment: Andy aka.. would you please tell me what type of voltage amplifier you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

A  C + L + C resonator, for a narrow-band sin, called a "PI" filter, may work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I don't any filter. I need an amplifier.